# Most Useful ASP.NET Component

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, components

I found DevExpress http://go.devexpress.com/DevExpressDownload_DXperience.aspx component useful for `ASP.NET`.

Is there any useful component (free or not) for `ASP.NET` in `Visual Studio 2010`?

What is your favorite?

Comment: This question is pretty ambiguous.  Do you mean for best UI Component set (like Telerik)?  Do you live in a web forms world or MVC (where DevExpress isn't an option)?  Are you looking for best in terms of profiling your code (like ANTS)?  To speed your typing (like tabs studio)?  To help optimize your app (like SquishIt)?

Comment: And this is a quintessentially subjective question.  Should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress is best. I have tried each of them and no one comes even closer to where DevEx is. I would strongly suggest DevEx platofrm for .Net Developers.

DevExpress Rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) extensively.

It obviously requires MS AJAX and it may be showing its age a bit, but there are some great controls in there and you can't argue with the price ;)

Comment: -1 and no comments? Someone's having a bad day...